# Is Tornado using multiprocessing internally?

Tags: python, tornado

Is Tornado using the `multiprocessing` module internally?  Considering that Tornado, being a web server, needs to handle lots of concurrent requests, I think it makes sense for Tornado to use `multiprocessing` and therefore take full advantage of multiple cores.

If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't not use multiprocessing.  Instead, it uses non-blocking IO (only one thread and one process).  See [this blog post](http://golubenco.org/2009/09/19/understanding-the-code-inside-tornado-the-asynchronous-web-server-powering-friendfeed/) for a description of how it works and why it is fast.

Other servers like [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) use separate processes to take advantage of multiple cores.